# Is this a valid identity: $\binom{n}r = \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n-k}{r-j} \binom{k}j$?

Tags: combinatorics

Is this a valid identity: $\binom{n}r = \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n-k}{r-j} \binom{k}j$?

I was looking at combinatorial proofs and considered a $r\times(n-r)$ checkerboard and counted the ways to start at the bottom left corner ending up at the top right corner, using only right and up movements.

The total ways is $\binom{n}r$.
Also, I consider the diagonal connecting the points $(n-r-k,r)$ and $(n-r,r-k)$.
Every path must pass through this diagonal.
This was a bit difficult for me to see, so I considered the cases when $k=1,2,3,4$.
$k=1: \binom{n}r = \binom{n-1}{r} + \binom{n-1}{r-1}$
$k=2: \binom{n}r = \binom{n-2}{r} + 2\binom{n-2}{r-1} + \binom{n-2}{r-2}$
$k=3: \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-3}{r} + 3\binom{n-3}{r-1} + 3\binom{n-3}{r-2} + \binom{n-3}{r-3}$
$k=4: \binom{n}r = \binom{n-4}{r} + 4\binom{n-4}{r-1} + 6\binom{n-4}{r-2} + 4\binom{n-4}{r-3} + \binom{n-4}{r-4}$

(The coefficients were found by literally counting the steps, so I couldn't think of it using binomial coefficient)

So it looks like to me that if I continue this pattern for k=j, then $$ \binom{n}r = \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n-k}{r-j} \binom{k}j. $$

But checking online shows that it isn't correct:
[W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%20binomial(n,r)%20%2B%20sum%20from%20j%3D0%20to%20k%20of%20binomial(n-k,r-j)*binomial(k,j))

If it is correct, is there a way to think of the coefficients (e.g. in $j=4$, we have coefficients $1,4,6,4,1$ in front of the $\binom{n-4}r, \binom{n-4}{r-1}, \binom{n-4}{r-2},\binom{n-4}{r-3},\binom{n-4}{r-4}$)

Comment: What is $k$ in this context?

Comment: Sorry, let me rewrite the details.

Comment: I had originally meant the diagonal which is defined  by connecting the points  
$(n-r-k,r)$ and $(n-r,r-k)$

Comment: Yes it is valid ... It is called the Vandermonde convolution identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert that identity to my one. The closest I got using that identity was  
$$\binom{n}{r} = \sum_{j=0}^r \binom{n-k}j \binom{k}{r-j}.$$  
and their upper limit is $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct identity is
$$\binom{n}{r} = \sum_{j=0}^r \binom{n-k}{r-j} \binom{k}{j}$$
That is, the upper limit of the sum should be $r$, not $k$.

Here's a combinatorial argument. First note that $\binom{n}{r}$ is the number of $r$-element subsets of an $n$-element set. Suppose your $n$-element set contains $k$ objects of one type (say, cats) and $n-k$ elements of another (say, dogs). In any given $r$-element subset, there will be exactly $j$ cats and $r-j$ dogs for some $0 \le j \le r$; these choices of $j$ partition the set of $r$-element subsets, and there are $\binom{n-k}{r-j} \binom{k}{j}$ subsets containing exactly $r-j$ of the $n-k$ dogs and exactly $j$ of the $k$ cats. Thus the arrive at the above identity.

As stated, your identity doesn't type-check when $r<k$, since then $r-k < 0$ and your sum contains binomial coefficients with negative arguments.

Comment: The upper limit can be $r$ just as well, as long as binomial coefficients are properly defined ($\dbinom{n}{k} = 0$ for $k \notin \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: I guess so; and if $k<r$ then the terms for $j=k+1,\dots,r$ are all zero anyway, since $\binom{k}{j} = 0$ for $j>k$. So I concede that the identity with $r$ replaced by $k$ is still valid if you adopt that convention.

Comment: Could we also have this identity instead?  
$$\binom{n}r = \sum_{j=0}^r \binom{n-k}j \binom{k}{r-j}$$  
  
Using your reasonings where there can be $j$ **dogs** instead of $j$ cats?

Comment: Yes. That's just a re-indexing of the sum, obtained by substituting $r-j$ for $j$.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial coefficients can be expressed as the coefficients of certain terms in a given function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n-k}{r-j} = [x^{r-j}]: (1+x)^{n-k} = [x^{r}]: x^j (1+x)^{n-k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Using this we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=0}^{k}  \binom{n-k}{r-j}\binom{k}{j}  = [x^{r}]: \sum_{j=0}^{k}  \binom{k}{j}x^j (1+x)^{n-k} = [x^{r}]:  (1+x)^{n} =\binom{n}{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @CliveNewstead well spotted ... it was a typo ... corrected now.

Comment: @CliveNewstead If $r-j<0$ then $ \binom{n-k}{r-j} =0$ and the sum includes extra terms that are zero. This does not effect the conclusion when you ask for the coefficient of $x^r$. But, yes strictly speaking the upper limit of the sum should be $ \min (r,k)$, I have implictly assumed that $r>k$.